# PhpStorm running script on server with argument

Tags: phpstorm

I have a project built by phpStorm located in server root (so called in place server).

Normally, we invoke this in a browser like this:

```
get.php?nStart=1&nEnd=10&type=184
```

How can I run it on server with arguments in phpStorm (or jump to browser from phpStorm)?

Comment: `Run | Edit Configurations...` -- create new Run/Debug configuration of most suitable type and use it.

Comment: @LazyOne My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Make a 'web application' configuration and type the parameter in 'StartUrl',
And it goes fine.